# How to make an HTTP POST request to a URL with the JSON string as the body part

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, http

I was assigned a coding challenge to complete. The challenge has multiple parts, and the final part is uploading to a private GitHub repo and submitting a completion request by making a POST request under certain conditions.

I have successfully completed the other parts of the challenge and am stuck on submitting the request. The submission has to follow these rules:

> > Build your solution request
>
> First, construct a JSON string like below:
>
> {
>
> ```
> "github_url": "https://github.com/YOUR_ACCOUNT/GITHUB_REPOSITORY",
>
> "contact_email": "YOUR_EMAIL"
> ```
>
> }
>
> Fill in your email address for YOUR_EMAIL, and the private Github
> repository with your solution in YOUR_ACCOUNT/GITHUB_REPOSITORY. Then,
> make an HTTP POST request to the following URL with the JSON string as
> the body part.
>
> CHALLENGE_URL
>
> Content type
>
> The Content-Type: of the request must be application/json.
>
> Authorization
>
> The URL is protected by HTTP Basic Authentication, which is explained
> on Chapter 2 of RFC2617, so you have to provide an Authorization:
> header field in your POST request.
>
> For the userid of HTTP Basic Authentication, use the same email
> address you put in the JSON string. For the password , provide a
> 10-digit time-based one time password conforming to RFC6238 TOTP.
> Authorization password
>
> For generating the TOTP password, you will need to use the following
> setup:
>
> You have to generate a correct TOTP password according to RFC6238
> TOTP's Time Step X is 30 seconds. T0 is 0. Use HMAC-SHA-512 for the
> hash function, instead of the default HMAC-SHA-1. Token shared secret
> is the userid followed by ASCII string value "APICHALLENGE" (not
> including double quotations). Shared secret examples
>
> For example, if the userid is "email@example.com", the token shared
> secret is "email@example.comAPICHALLENGE" (without quotes).
>
> If your POST request succeeds, the server returns HTTP status code 200
> .

I am using Nodejs to make the request and have tried every possible solution for the past 3 days but I can't pass this error: 'Access Denied: Invalid token, wrong code'.

Here is what I came up with:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const base64 = require('base-64');
const utf8 = require('utf8');
const hotpTotpGenerator = require('hotp-totp-generator');

const ReqJSON = {
  github_url: GITHUB_URL,
  contact_email: MY_EMAIL
};

const stringData = JSON.stringify(ReqJSON);
const URL = '';
const sharedSecret = ReqJSON.contact_email + "HENNGECHALLENGE003";

const MyTOTP = hotpTotpGenerator.totp({
  key: sharedSecret,
  T0: 0,
  X: 30,
  algorithm: 'sha512',
  digits: 10,
});

const authStringUTF = ReqJSON.contact_email + ':' + MyTOTP;
const bytes = utf8.encode(authStringUTF);
const encoded = base64.encode(bytes);

const createReq = async () => {
  try {
    const config = {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         Authorization: 'Basic ' + encoded,
      },
    };

    console.log('Making request', { URL, ReqJSON, config });

    const response = await axios.post(URL, stringData, config);
    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.response.data);
  }
};

createReq();
```

I would be more than happy to get an assistance. I have gone a long way in completing 2 out of the 3 tasks so I can't afford to quite at this very last stage.

Comment: You don't need `withCredentials`, that's for cookie-based authentication. FYI, Axios supports basic credentials via the `auth` config and handles JS objects as JSON by default

Comment: Also, try not to overwrite `URL` with a local variable as it already exists ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Comment: Re my first comment, try `axios.post(url, ReqJSON, { auth: { username: ReqJSON.contact_email, password: MyTOTP } })`

Comment: Could your problem be that it says to use `APICHALLENGE` in the shared secret but you are using `HENNGECHALLENGE003`. Also, make sure the clock is correct on whatever system this is running

Comment: Hello @Phil, thank you for your response. It means a lot to me. However, I have tried following your suggestion but it returned an error. I replaced `axios.post(URL, stringData, config);` with `axios.post(url, ReqJSON, { auth: { username: ReqJSON.contact_email, password: MyTOTP } })`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: What error? Same one as before or a different one? There wasn't really anything particularly wrong with your original code, my first three comments were merely suggestions. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70616755/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-to-a-url-with-the-json-string-as-the-body-part#comment124833793_70616755) however is an important one to answer

Comment: Hello again @Phil. It isn't an error per sa. The message reads something like this: `(node:6096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of...`. Also, `HENNGECHALLENGE003` is the required name. That's a typo from my path. I've also checked the clock and can confirm that it's correct. I'm wondering if the challenge could be that I didn't initiate the program well. I just don`t know what the problem is. I've been stucked on this for the past three days. I try doing it all day.

Comment: That would be the part in your `catch` block. Try just `console.error(err)` instead. Depending on the error, `err.response` might not be set